# Could I have Java code that only runs when a dependency/module is loaded?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I am looking to make a library for java that to keep it lightweight I want to keep some code separated into modules e.g. separate libraries The purpose of this is the modules will essentially hold the code for processing and handling different 3d model types.

So if I'm loading a `.dae` file I will need the Collada Module/library.

I want it all to be processed under 1 class so instead of doing `ColladaProcessor.process()`

you simple do Dmal.process() and when provided with a .dae file it will trigger and run the ColladaProcessor.process().

```
// Code Example
class Dmal {
  public void process(String fileName) {
    //Code to load file to input stream
    InputStream inputStream = ...

    if(fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".dae")) {
       // Code should only work if the dependency (dmal-dae) exists
       // If not throw custom Module not found exception.
       ColladaProcessor.process(inputStream);
    }

  }
}
```

To recap I'm looking for a solution to only run the code if the dependency exists, if this is done through interface or something.

Comment: You should look into [ServiceLoaders](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html). Those allow you to load all implementations of an interface at runtime, based on configuration files in the jars on the classpath.

Comment: That worked perfectly Im using the AutoService library from google and it worked fine. I will provide a example of my solution later on.

Comment: Excellent! I like AutoService for this purpose too.